# How to escape single quotes in Jenkins pipeline sed command?

Tags: bash, jenkins, groovy, sed, jenkins-pipeline

I cant seem to figure out how to get to write this in Jenkins pipeline?

`sed -i "txt" "s/id 'com.github'  ver '1.0'/id 'com.github'/g" file.txt`

This is what i have been trying so far

`sh """sed -i "txt" "s/id \'com.github\'  ver \'1.0\'/id \'com.github\'/g" file.txt"""`

I have a file with content -

```
id 'com.github'  ver '1.0'
```

I want to remove

```
ver '1.0'
```

from

```
id 'com.github'  ver '1.0'
```

using a bash command. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me in Jenkinsfile -

```
script {
      dir('mydir') {
          def command = $/sed -i "s/id 'com.github'  ver '1.0'/id 'com.github'/" ./file.txt/$
          SED_OUT = sh(returnStdout: true, script: command)
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `ed` instead.

```
 printf '%s\n' "s/\(id 'com.github'\)  ver '1.0'/\\1/" wq | ed file.txt
```

Note that the quoting issue can be fixed in `sed` (you are unnecessarily escaping the single quotes), but `ed` is more standard and designed for what you are trying to do: edit a file in place.

Comment: Not sure if the command makes sense to me. I have updated the question to be more clear. what is wq? ed is text editor, how can I use it for text change on bash cmd line?

Comment: I tried without quotes and that doesnt seem to work either - 
$ cat /tmp/t.txt
test2
id 'com.github'  ver '1.0'
test


$ sh """sed -i "txt" "s/id 'com.github'  ver '1.0'/id 'com.github'/g" /tmp/t.txt"""
sh: sed -i txt s/id: No such file or directory

Comment: You aren't changing text on the command line. You are editing the file `file.txt` in-place. `"""` isn't part of shell syntax; that's syntax used by Jenkins to specify the string to pass to `sh`.

Comment: That is, `sh """..."""` is not itself a shell command; it's a Jenkins directive indicating that `...` should be executed by `sh`.